# how to add rows to a table in angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

i have this table that uses data from a JSON file, how do i add a function that allows the user to enter data into text fields and add that data into the table?

this is a simple preview of what i have, it displays the data in the JSON in a table

```
<table>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> Job </th>

    <tr *ngFor="let emp of employe">
        <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.empId}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.empJob}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Name: <input type="text">
ID:   <input type="text">
Job:  <input type="text">

<button> Add </button>
```

*note: i don't want to add to the JSON file (i know it's not possible), just the table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to add button click handler `addHandler()` which will then insert new element in the array `employee` and simply bind this array to your table. So everytime you press add button with new data in the input fields new entry will be added to your table `employee`.

> .ts file

```
 name = ''; 
 id = '';
 job = '';
 employee = [];
 addHandler(){
 this.employee.push({
        empName:this.name,
        empId:this.id,
        empJob:this.job
  })
 }
```

> .html file

```
<table>
<th> Name    </th>
<th> ID    </th>
<th> Job    </th>

<tr *ngFor="let emp of employee">
    <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.empId}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.empJob}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>

Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"><br>
ID:   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id"><br>
Job:  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="job"><br>

<button (click)="addHandler()"> Add </button>
```

Working demo : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsx9ka)